# WAMP on Windows EC2 Instance

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have a wamp server that doesn't have a port 3306 even tho I installed the wamp, it gives me this error when trying to test the port of mysql

```
Port 3306 is not found associated with TCP protocol
```

and when I use netstat -a, it doesn't have a port 3306.

Comment: SOunds like the database has not started. Did you check the mysql error log for anything useful. `C:\wamp64\logs`

Comment: It doesn't log anything about mysql, it mostly logs mariadb, which uses port 3307

Comment: Do you only have mariaDB running? Look at the Windows System Event Log

Comment: As of now, only my PHP and Mariadb runs which is 2 of 3 services.

Comment: Then use 3307, not 3306 or modify mariadb configuration to listen on 3306. Btw, mariadb is a fork of mysql, so the two are very similar, but not the same. Or unistall mariadb and install mysql and configure it to listen on 3306.

Comment: The problem is, in my local pc, it can run both sql and mariadb, while on the ec2 windows instance mysql doesnt work.

Comment: PHP does not run as a service, Apache will be the other service

Comment: Does MySQL attemp to start?

Comment: How do u know if it attempts to start? I try to click the start service on the wamp but doesnt do anything, I also checked the bin folder it has the mysql folder.